# Signing in javascript vs C# is giving me different answers

Tags: javascript, c#, sign

I have code in C# and the equivalent code in Javascript, but they are ouputting different values, they use the same private key and string to sign. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here:

Javascript (using jsrsa.js library)

```
let requestStringToSign = "test string";

let sig = new KJUR.crypto.Signature({ "alg": "SHA512withRSA" });
sig.init(this._rsaPrivateKey);
sig.updateString(requestStringToSign);
let sigValueHex = this.hexToBase64(sig.sign());
```

C#

```
string requestStringToSign = "test string";

using (RSA rsa = _privateCert1.GetRSAPrivateKey())
using (var sha512 = SHA512.Create())
{
     var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(requestStringToSign);
     var hash = sha512.ComputeHash(bytes);
     var signatureBytes = rsa.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
     var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
}
```

Comment: Which one is the one you expected? Probably due to encoding. Try `var bytes 
 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestStringToSign);`

Comment: You need to figure out which encoding `updateString` in javascript uses. But I doubt it's UTF-16 (which you use in c#). Try with UTF-8

Comment: Brilliant that fixed it. I'd googled around a bit about JS string encoding and concluded it was UTF-16, but guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After days of researching and trial and error, I found this discussion and the comments led me to the answer.  Here's my formalized answer for anyone still looking for it.

When validating in C# or VB, you have to account for various encodings.

```
Dim symmetricKey = (New Guid(secret)).ToByteArray() 'This array encoding is used by .NET

Dim symmetricKeyUTF8 = (Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret)) 'This is used by Javascript and our Postman example

Dim issuerSigningKeys = New List(Of SecurityKey) From {New SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey), New SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKeyUTF8)}
```

Also always check the secret is the same, no matter how obvious it is.